# How to get client ID and secret key from paypal account

Tags: api, paypal

Using developer account of paypal I could get client ID and secret key by creating an app but not with the live account.

I am using REST API for transactions on my website where I ask users(who has paypal accounts) to enter their client ID and secret key, and use this info to transfer the money into their account, payments are done by credit card.
It is working fine with the developer account but where is the option to get client ID and secret key from live account ?

OR
Is there any other way I can do this, I want to transfer the money to paypal accounts and payments are always done from credit card.

Comment: I have a same kind of problem.I implemented RestAPI in POS application (desktop). Now I want to go live. How a merchant will get his client id and client secret ?

Comment: This issue is still not resolved, right? As i'm facing too :)

Answer (score 35):

This has changed at PayPal.  (Quite a lot actually!)

1. As before - log in to your PayPal account at: https://developer.paypal.com
2. PayPal, like everyone else, Wants to show ads.  So you may have to look around to actually get to the developer website.  Just keep looking until you get to where it has "Log in" at the top.
3. Once logged in click on the "Dashboard".
4. Once to the Dashboard click on the "My Account" FIRST- BEFORE anything else.
5. Once to the "My Account" part make sure you can do everything (ie: there are GREEN check marks in both columns. Or if you don't want to do some things - make sure they are NOT check marked.)
6. To activate (or Enable) something just click on the link and follow what it says to do.
7. Once through with that click on the "My Apps" link on the left.  If you are no longer where you can do that then go back to #2 above and start over.
8. Once on the "My Apps" page; click on the link to "Create App".
9. This will ask you to name the app and select an account to develop the app with.
10. Once through putting in all of that information - you are through and PayPal will give you all of the information you need.

I don't know about anyone else - but that's just a few more steps than just logging in and clicking a button.  :-)

Comment: I agree, I am still unable to find the option to create clientid and secret, horrible new design.

Answer (score 7):

You should use the new Developer Portal to create your Apps and get sandbox and live credentials for each: https://developer.paypal.com/

Comment: Direct link: https://developer.paypal.com/developer/applications/

Answer (score 3):

Log in to https://developer.paypal.com and click the Applications tab.

On the https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/applications/myapps click Create App.

On the Create New App page, provide an app name.

Click Create App, and then review the information displayed about your app (as described below)

now you will get client id and secret key